# Format datetime fields in bcp output files in Sybase ASE (or with Sed)

Tags: mysql, datetime, sed, sybase, bcp

I am trying to build a database in mysql with bcp files which are created from a Sybase ASE database.

1. I create from Sybase the ddl and I transform it in a Mysql ddl.
2. I generate the bcp.out files with Sybase.
3. When I am trying to insert this bcp.out files in the new Mysql database, I get a problem with the format of the datetime fields.

What I have in bcp.out files:

```
iker1 0 1 6 3 1 0 1 Sep 16 2011 11:20:05:950AM
iker2 1 1 6 3 1 0 1 Jun 15 2012 11:20:05:750AM 
gdf34 0 2 6 3 1 0 1 Feb 05 2014 11:20:05:016AM
```

What I expect in bcp.out files:

```
iker1 0 1 6 3 1 0 1 2011-09-16 11:20:05.950
iker2 1 1 6 3 1 0 1 2012-06-15 11:20:05.750
gdf34 0 2 6 3 1 0 1 2014-02-05 11:20:05.016
```

Is there any way of formatting/configuring the output of the date fields in the Sybase Central when we are doing the bcp.out file?

Is there a (simple) way to do it (with sed)?

Comment: To do it with bcp, you would use a view, and convert the datetime to the format you wish within the view.  From there you can bcp out of the view.

Comment: @MichaelGardner, yes, a 24 hour clock

Comment: @MichaelGardner I did a view like --> create view ...,  CONVERT(DATETIME, change_date, 21) as change_date from names and I get the same result. Did I miss something?

Comment: Check my answer - it should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one method of doing it from the database end.

create a view on your table, defining the date conversion you wish to see.  In this case, the following statement will retrieve the date in the format you want.

```
select convert(char(10),your_date_column,23)+" "+convert(char(8),your_date_column,8)+"."+convert(char(3),datepart(ms,your_date_column))
```

So that can be combined with the creation of a view on the table:

```
create view my_view (col1, col2, col3, your_date_column) as
select col1, col2, col3, convert(char(10),your_date_column,23)+" "+convert(char(8),your_date_column,8)+"."+convert(char(3),datepart(ms,your_date_column))
from your_table
```

At this point, you can use `bcp` to extract data from the view.

```
bcp MyDB..my_view out my_data.out -Uusername -Ppassword -Sservername -c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/@\([a-zA-Z]\{3\}\) \([^@]*-@@-\)$/@\2\1/
     s/Jan$/01/;s/Feb$/02/;s/Jun$/06/;s/Sep$/09/;s/Dec$/12/
     s/@\([0-9][0-9]\) \([0-9]\{4\}\)\( [^@]*-@@-\)\([0-9][0-9]\)$/@\2-\4-\1\3/
     s/..-@@-/-@@-/' YourFile
```

explanation:

1. isolate the month at the end
2. change the month name in index
3. introduce the index in date and reformat it
4. remove the AM/PM (sed is not strong in math so take the easiest for me but on same principle of month, could adapt the hour)

complete the month to be fully working on second line.

I suspect that time have to be changed also (only AM hour are here), this sed don't change it